# Linking two lists together, one job board, the other field personal, and getting a rolling schedule in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have been tasked with creating a Field Job board for my company and was wondering how to integrate two separate lists. One has all the Field jobs: Location, time to arrive on job, Field worker dispatched, time job is finished, and job status. I am trying to create another list where it will have the field personals in order and sections based on their status, if they are in the field, on days off, and available. I also want them in order of last job completed, those go to the bottom of the available section order. What would be the best way to go about doing this and linking the two in a way where when I input a name for a job, it automatically inputs info on the field personal list?

Answer (score 0):

The questions is a bit vague so it is hard to grasp what you are trying to achieve. But I believe you can try to use connections for that. Which also works for modern pages.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

This video also might help: it shows how to connect webparts to show specific content when selected from another view.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5tGR6Eh_Jo

If that is not specific enough for you. Please try to elaborate more, give more details about the lists or try to show a simple table how it should look. ex.: the list you getting the data from, what data and passing down to the other view/section and what then should be displayed.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit hard to fulfill your requirements with only SharePoint lists. I assume you want to make the person list only showing employee availability. There are options you can check for the one fits you best.

1. Create a simple personnel list displaying all the members. Use a Workflow or Flow to update the personnel list based on the job list. Here is a [example](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-update-an-item-in-a-SharePoint-list-base-on-the-changes/m-p/101738#M9942).
2. Use PowerApps forms to customize the personnel list forms, create datasource to your job list, hide person who is not available and sort all of them.